# Need interpretation for this code

Tags: python

```
n1, n2, n3 = (n + [None]*2)[:3]
```

I just very briefly want to know what this does, how this works.
Is this like a list comprehension, as long as I offer a list or iterable with enough variables will it assign the n1 = iterable[0]?

Also why does having [:3] on the end of the brackets limit the length?

I understand why [None] is there, just in case the length of n is less than 3 but can someone give me a bit more info?

I have only been coding for about a week and need a bit of help interpreting.

Comment: FWIW, `n` _should_ be a list (or a suitably-defined custom object). It can't be just any iterable. Eg, if `n` is a tuple you'll get `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`. Similarly, it won't work if `n` is a string.

Answer (score 7):

This takes the first three elements of `n`, padding with `None` if it has fewer than three elements.

`(n + [None]*2)` concatenates a list of `[None, None]` to the list `n`, and as you say, `[:3]` takes the first three items of the resulting list. These three items are then unpacked to the variables `n1`, `n2` and `n3`.

For example:

```
In [1]: n = ['One', 'Two']

In [2]: n1, n2, n3 = (n + [None]*2)[:3]

In [3]: print n1
One

In [4]: print n2
Two

In [5]: print n3
None
```

But if `n` has three or more items in it, you just get those three items as `n1`, `n2` and `n3`.

As others have noted below, this code will fail if `n` is the empty list, since then `(n + [None]*2)` will only have two items in it. It can be sliced OK: `(n + [None]*2)[:3]` returns a list with those two items, but then the unpacking to three variables fails. Whether the resulting `ValueError` in this case is the intended exception to be raised or whether the code should be `n1, n2, n3 = (n + [None]*3)[:3]` so as to return `None` into each of the variables is something only the original programmer knows. This would usually warrant a comment in the code.

Comment: `n` should be list. It would be nice if you mention this though

Comment: True, that: I've expanded my answer a bit. Though `n` isn't really a great choice of name for a `list` IMO.

Comment: Its possibly worth mentioning that if `n` is the empty list then `(n + [None]*2)[:3]` will succeed,resulting in `[None, None]`, but then the unpacking to the tuple `n1, n2, n3` will fail.

Comment: @xnx No need to be humble about your opinion: `n` is a lousy name for a list, especially when it's used with the overloaded `+` operator, and especially as a name for a list of things whose elements are named by n1, n2, n3, . All of these names are conventionally used for integers.

Comment: As @PM 2Ring mentions, the statement fails if `n` is empty. Probably `[None]*3` should be have been used - that would be safe.

Comment: @BrianO: OTOH, depending on context it may be desirable for the program to raise `ValueError` & crash if `n` is an empty list, eg if the logic of the rest of the program is such that `n` should _never_ be empty.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Yes true. We don't know context. Sometimes a function or method requires an argument to be nonempty, and a good way to enforce it is to fail when the requirement isn't met. Or perhaps based on what has already happened `n` is certifiably, assertably nonempty. Or, as in your possible scenario, maybe the rest of the program requires `n` nonempty, so this line combines getting something useful done with asserting that `n` is truthy. In the first and last situations, it's best to actually `assert n` too.

Comment: @BrianO, PM 2Ring You're both right. Ideally there'd be a comment in the code clarifying the intention here.

Comment: Finally, re the bad variable names: maybe this is a brain-teaser, deliberately obfuscated, e.g. an exercise, quiz question, etc. I'd like to think it's not from production code :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not list comprehension.  Presumably, `n` is a list, [or anything that can be the left-operand of concatenation by the `+` operator when called with the suitable right-operand, under suitable implementation of `__add__` or `__radd__`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  The `+` operator on lists concatenates them together to create a new list, and the `[:3]` part is just syntax sugar for getting a slice of the list.  You really should look up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: I know what you mean, however, the result of `n + [None]*2` isn't _necessarily_ concatenation: if `n` is an instance of a class with an appropriate `__add__` method, then `n + some_list` can return anything the class's implementer wants it to.

Comment: Well, it's not as general as all that: `n` can be anything that be a *first* operand of the `+` operator *when the second operand is a list* -- here, `[None]*2`. It can't be a tuple, for example (raises TypeError).

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm not implying that it is necessarily concatenation.

Comment: @BrianO acknowledged.